# How i can make a material checkbox filled in gray when is not checked?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-animations

I'm trying to fill a [Angular Material Checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) with a `background-color: gray` when is not checked, and when it is checked, fill with `background-color: red`.

This is what i have been tried:

```
mat-checkbox:not(.mat-checkbox-checked) .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #C3C3C3;
}

mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: red
}
```

This way is working like i expect, but when i check/descheck is showing a white background and the animation don't seems to work so good.

[My stackblitz demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcn28z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the angular materials animation by importing the `NoopAnimationsModule` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/NoopAnimationsModule)).

E.g.:

```
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ NoopAnimationsModule ],
  exports: [
     ...
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcn28z-xcwtau).